# How do I check for command line parameters in sqlplus?

Tags: command-line, sql

I am trying to write a sql file which will run under sqlplus. My goal is to create a mechanism by which sqlplus will prompt for password if no parameters are passed, and if &1 is present, continue to run with the value taken as password, without prompting the user for password. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sqlplus username @sqlfile.sql
```

to have the password entered by the user or

```
sqlplus username/password @sqlfile.sql
```

for fully automatic execution.

Don't forget to end your SQL script with `exit`.

Comment: actually the script is a little bit complex with multiple "disconnect" and "conn" statement with different users, currently i have it prompting for the passwords, i cannot create a new script, and somehow modify this to work with automated systems like jenkins

Comment: what i'm looking for is an sqlplus equivalent of a bash snippet like this if [ $# -lt 3 ];then; <PROMPT>; else ; <CONTINUE WITH $1, $2 and $3>; fi;